# Infinite recursion on JSON mapping of bidirectional @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have following scenario: There are companies and employees. Each company has a set of employees. Each employee can work for several companies. So I implemented following relationships:

Company.class:

```
@JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") )
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

Employee.class:

```
@JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") )
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Company> companies;
```

The goal is the ability to fetch `List<Employee>`, each Employee with `Set<Company>`, or another scenario, to fetch `List<Company>`, but without fetching related `Set<Employee>`. But if I fetch a `Company` by id, related `Set<Employee>` should also be fetched.

What I did in daos:
If I fetch Lists in both cases, it work as supposed to work without issues: what is eager - is fetched, what is lazy - is not fetched. 
To fetch Employee by id I do following, and it fetches an Employee with not empty `Set<Company>`, as I expect it to:

```
public Employee find(Long id) {
        Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
        return employee;
```

To fetch Company by id with not empty `Set<Employee>` I tried:

variant 1:

```
public Company find(Long id) {
        TypedQuery<Company> query = em.createQuery("select distinct e from Company e left outer join fetch e.employees where e.company_id=:company_id", Company.class);
        query.setParameter("company_id", id);
        Company company = query.getSingleResult();
        return company;
    }
```

variant2:

```
 public Company find(Long id) {
            Company company = entityManager.find(Company.class, id);
            Hibernate.initialize(company.getEmployees());
            return company;
        }
```

As I see both variant1 and variant2 give `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException` due to the infinite recursion during JSON serialization. 
I tried to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` , but then Set annotated with `@JsonBackReference` is never fetched regarless any `join fetch` or `Hibernate.initialize` I use. 
So what is the correct approach to implement what I need? Thank you.

Comment: if that relation is bidirectional, where is the "mappedBy" ???

Comment: @NeilStockton Is this wrong way to implement? It works fine. Should I await some problems due to this implementation?

Comment: It is NOT bidirectional without a mappedBy. Currently you have 2 1-N relations, without linkage

Comment: @NeilStockton OK, thanks for clarifying. Does it matter for my problem? Should I refactor? Could you describe possible problems if I leave it as is?

Comment: @NeilStockton Thank you for the hint that it is not bidirectional. I changed it and it solved the problem. Please see Update 1 of the answer I checked as a solution. I am still learning, so sometimes lack of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I found a solution: using `@JsonIdentityInfo`. More information [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html)
Now my entities look like that (removed all unrelated fields and methods), and they work exactly as I need them to:

Company.class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="company_id")
public class Company {
     @JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") )
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employee.class:

```
 @Entity
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="employee_id")
 public class Employee {
     @JoinTable(name = "company_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") )
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private Set<Company> companies;
 }
```

I hope it will help to somebody.

**UPDATE 1**
Actually, as  Neil Stockton noticed, the mapping is not quite correct and is not legal bidirectional. So I just changed one of entities like below, then no additional annotations needed to avoid infinite recursion

```
     @Entity
     public class Employee {
         @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="employees")
         private Set<Company> companies;
     }
```

I think it's important update.

Comment: thanks for the Update - it solved my issue :) - I still get stackoverflow error from one of the sides.. I even used FetchType.Lazy on both without a result